# How to stop a javascript function from returning value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript method for validating the inputs in form and then return the serialised form data if it has passed validation.

```
function getFormData(form)  
{  
  if(validation failed)  
  {  
    alert("Invalid input"); 
    return;   
    //stop execution;  
  }  
  return $(form).serialize();  
}
```

I have another function calling the above function.

```
var data = getFormData();
```

The problem I face is, if validation failed, the code execution doesn't stop execution. How to stop execution after alert ? I tried `return false;` and then having a `if` check to see if it has returned `false`, it works. But is there any other way to stop executing immediately after alert. Because, I need to call this function at multiple places.

Comment: if its a event do preventDefault; return false is fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript stop execution abort or exit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834831/javascript-stop-execution-abort-or-exit)

Comment: consider using "else"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
throw new Error('Generated error manually to stop execution of script');
```

Or link to more sophisticated answer

[How to terminate the script in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550574/how-to-terminate-the-script-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var isallpassed=0;    
function getFormData(form)  
    {  
        isallpassed=validation1 failed;
        isallpassed= isallpassed && validation2 failed;
        if(isallpassed)  
        {  
         return $(form).serialize(); 
        }  
      else{
        alert("Invalid input");
       }
    }
```